# Inject a textbox in WebForms and retain the value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms page that I would like to inject some additional controls into at runtime.  Currently I am achieving this in the Page_Load event using a Literal control.

For example the page looks like this (note that the TextBox1 is not an asp control just to show that it works):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">   
    <input id="TextBox1" type="text" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:Literal>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />   
</asp:Content>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal1.Visible = true;
    if (!IsPostBack) Literal1.Text = "<input id=\"TextBox2\" type=\"text\" runat=\"server\"/>";
}
```

This works fine and both textboxes appear on the screen but if I type a value in to both and trigger a postback only the value of TextBox1 is retained.

I have tried moving my code to OnPreRender and OnPreLoad but still have the same issue.

I have noticed that when I view the page source TextBox1 has a UniqueId (e.g. ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1) while Textbox2 still has `runat="server"` as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject server controls like this. You would need to add them as suggested in @Arvin's answer.

However, you use inject non-ASP.NET HTML controls similar to what you are doing and get their values.

From your code change the input's `id` to a `name` and drop the `runat="server"`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal1.Visible = true;
    if (!IsPostBack) Literal1.Text = "<input name=\"TextBox2\" type=\"text\" />";
}
```

Then you can get it's value on postback:

```
string textbox2value = Request.Form["TextBox2"];
```

Then, if you want to add the control on postback with it's value:

```
Literal1.Text = "<input name=\"TextBox2\" type=\"text\" value=\"" +
    Server.HTMLEncode(textbox2value) + "\" />";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to inject a textbox you should use placeholder like this :

```
<input id="TextBox1" type="text" runat="server"/>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plh" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TextBox = new TextBox();
    TextBox.ID = "TextBox2";
    plh.Controls.Add(TextBox);
}


 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Text1 = TextBox1.Value;
    var Text2 = Request.Form["TextBox2"];
}
```

Comment: It's a legacy product and the skin is injected as raw HTML, I don't know how to parse it